# Add range of ips to centos networking?

Tags: centos, linux, linux-networking

I got an extra /28 ip range for a centos based VPS. I am wondering how to add them as range in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` , instead of creating 13 `ifcfg-venet0:x` files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a range using something like: 

File: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-venet0-range1

`IPADDR_START=192.168.1.2`
`IPADDR_END=192.168.1.100`
`CLONENUM_START=0`

Then run:
`ifup ifcfg-venet0-range1`

(Replace 192.168.1.X with your IP's as required)

Comment: I think clonenum_start should be 2 if you already have 2 ips for example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My DC likes to give us /27's made up of non-connected IPs for our VPS server. I can't seem to find a script that will help us copy and paste the IP list in and create the necessary files /edits. It's a huge problem as the "random" IPs don't fit into our inventory system either.

I use the clonenum range scripts when we get actual ranges for the VPS masters since we're using CentOS. I did see a script once for Debian which would have worked but the syntax and formatting was so screwed up we couldn't get it to function.